# How can I make 2 cells inside a CSS display: table-row occupy 50% of the row?

Tags: html, css

I have the following HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="def" style="margin-bottom: 4rem; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; margin-top: 7.25rem; width: 90%;">

        <div id="abc" style="display: table-row; width: 100%;">
            <div style="width: 50%; height: 20px; background-color: green;">
                I want this to fill almost 45% of the width of the screen
            </div>
            <div style="width: 50%; height: 20px; background-color: red;">
                I want this to fill almost 45% of the width of the screen
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I tried this code above but it seems like the DIVs inside the table-row don't expand in width. If possible I would like solution within the div with id of abc as I cannot change the style of the div `def`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do following to get desired result

**[FIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/richasingh/2hpdn611/7/)**

**CSS**

```
.container {
    margin-bottom: 4rem;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-top: 7.25rem;
    width: 90%;
    border:2px solid;
    background:yellow;
}
.subcontainer {
    display: table-row;
    width: 100%;
}
.first {
    width: 50%;
    height: 20px;
    background-color: green;
    float:left;/***Use This***/

}
.second {
    width: 50%;
    height: 20px;
    background-color: red;
    float:right;/***Use This***/
}
```

Or you can use **table-cell**

**[FIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/2hpdn611/8/)**

```
.first {
    width: 50%;
    height: 20px;
    background-color: green;
    display:table-cell;/***Use This***/

}
.second {
    width: 50%;
    height: 20px;
    background-color: red;
    display:table-cell;/***Use This***/
}
```

**EDIT: It is always better to write CSS separately**

Answer (score 0):

utilize `float` property

```
<div id="def" style="margin-bottom: 4rem; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; margin-top: 7.25rem; width: 90%;">

        <div id="abc" style="display: table-row; width: 100%;">
            <div style="width: 50%; height: 20px; background-color: green; float:left">
                I want this to fill almost 45% of the width of the screen
            </div>
            <div style="width: 50%; height: 20px; background-color: red; float:right">
                I want this to fill almost 45% of the width of the screen
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Quite easy, if you want to make a table-like structure, use `display: table-cell;` on the divs:

```
 <div id="def" style="margin-bottom: 4rem; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; margin-top: 7.25rem; width: 90%; display: table;">

    <div id="abc" style="display: table-row; width: 100%;">
        <div style="display: table-cell; width: 50%; height: 20px; background-color: green;">
            I want this to fill almost 45% of the width of the screen
        </div>
        <div style="display: table-cell; width: 50%; height: 20px; background-color: red;">
            I want this to fill almost 45% of the width of the screen
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

You can also use `float: left;`, but since it's already a table in display, you might as well go on that way.

Edit: To be complete, I added a `display: table;` to the `#def` div.

You can see a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/931tmrwz/) of this. And as others have said as well, it is always better to separate the CSS from the HTML, as I've done in the fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

You need `display: table-cell;` on your divs that are inside `table-row`.

like so:

```
  <div id="def" style="margin-bottom: 4rem; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; margin-top: 7.25rem; width: 90%;">

        <div id="abc" style="display: table-row; width: 100%;">
            <div style="width: 50%; height: 20px; background-color: green; display:table-cell">
                I want this to fill almost 45% of the width of the screen
            </div>
            <div style="width: 50%; height: 20px; background-color: red; display:table-cell">
                I want this to fill almost 45% of the width of the screen
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0dwh1yxc/)

Floating works too (better for when you are supporting old IEs) but `display: table-cell;` is more in line with what you are doing.